# Android WebView inside a Fragment : How to make WebView goback?

Tags: android, webview

I want to know how can I make the WebView inside onCreateView in a Fragment go back if the back button is pressed. It has been asked here some time ago but it hasn't got any answer.
Can someone help me?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You will want to add the WebView to the BackStack of the FragmentManager. Look at the [FragmentManager Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager.html) for the specific syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I will look at this but I was also wondering, if I have more fragments with WebViews, can I make on the main Activity a big WebView with all settings, and fragments will be used only for WebView.loadUrl(url)? I have just began Android development :).

Answer (score 0):

**Inside of the your OnCreateView:**

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);

      mWebView = (WebView) view.findViewById(R.id.webView);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        mWebView.loadUrl(expertsUrl);

        return view;
    }


private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Ok! In your MainActivity you will write it:

```
     @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
if (WebViewFragment.mWebView!=null) {
            if (WebViewFragment.mWebView.canGoBack()) {
                WebViewFragment.mWebView.goBack();
            }
}
        }
```

WebViewFragment= This is your nameFragment that content the Webview

mWebView= The name of your WebView (id)

Now. Inside of your Fragment  you have to declare static global variable

```
public static Webview mWebView;
```

And that's it! Good luck!